# Change skype text alignment when language changes

Tags: skype, language-support

I know Skype for Linux isn't the same as Skype for Windows. In Windows, if I change the language to Hebrew, it changes the text alignment to "right to left" as it should and it's all fine. I recently installed Skype on Ubuntu, version 4.3 (the latest), and I discovered the Linux version doesn't have Hebrew on the list of languages.

So I tried using [SkypeInYourLanguage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/skypeinyourlang/files/Linux/) and added Arabic to Skype (also right to left), but it's still aligned left to right.

So how can I change the text alignment in Skype?

Comment: Hate it when that happens :) Try reading English aligned the wrong way! It may that it simply isn't programmed in  - it isn't an option...

Comment: @Tim But maybe it's possible to hack it to work somehow...

Comment: It may be... But it would probably break other things, just metaphorically clicking a change alignment button doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You can install *skype-translation-he* from [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gunnarhj/+archive/ubuntu/skype-translation), which will add Hebrew to the list of languages. Some strings seem to be right aligned at least.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't look for menu translation, I want the actual chat to be right to left, it's interesting because the skype notifications do display aligned right to left.

Comment: @shoham: Aha, I see. Right, the chat seems to be left aligned whatever you do...

Answer (score 0):

right-click in the "message writing"-window.
A menu appears: tick "Right-to-Left reading order"
(This works on windows skype-for-business for Office365)